# Creating PL/SQL procedure to fill intermediary table with random data

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, associative-array

As part of my classes on relational databases, I have to create procedures as part of package to fill some of the tables of an Oracle database I created with random data, more specifically the tables community, community_account and community_login_info (see ERD linked below). I succeeded in doing this for tables community and community_account, however I'm having some problems with generating data for table community_login_info. This serves as an intermediary table between the many to many relationship of community and community_account, linking the id's of both tables.

My latest approach was to create an associative array with the structure of the target table community_login_info. I then do a cross join of community and community_account (there's already random data in there) along with random timestamps, bulk collect that result into the variable of the associative array and then insert those contents into the target table community_login_info. But it seems I'm doing something wrong since Oracle returns error ORA-00947 'not enough values'. To me it seems all columns the target table get a value in the insert, what am I missing here? I added the code from my package body below.

[ERD snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55oAK.png)

```
PROCEDURE mass_add_rij_koppeling_community_login_info
IS
TYPE type_rec_communties_accounts IS RECORD
(type_community_id community.community_id%type,
type_account_id community_account.account_id%type,
type_start_timestamp_login community_account.start_timestamp_login%type,
type_eind_timestamp_login community_account.eind_timestamp_login%type);
TYPE type_tab_communities_accounts
IS TABLE of type_rec_communties_accounts
INDEX BY pls_integer;
t_communities_accounts type_tab_communities_accounts;
BEGIN
SELECT community_id,account_id,to_timestamp(start_datum_account) as start_timestamp_login, to_timestamp(eind_datum_account) as eind_timestamp_login 
BULK COLLECT INTO t_communities_accounts
FROM community
CROSS JOIN community_account
FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY;
FORALL i_index IN t_communities_accounts.first .. t_communities_accounts.last
SAVE EXCEPTIONS
INSERT INTO community_login_info (community_id,account_id,start_timestamp_login,eind_timestamp_login)
values (t_communities_accounts(i_index));
END mass_add_rij_koppeling_community_login_info;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error refers to the part:

```sql
INSERT INTO community_login_info (community_id,account_id,start_timestamp_login,eind_timestamp_login)
values (t_communities_accounts(i_index));
```

(By the way, the complete error message gives you the line number where the error is located, it can help to focus the problem)

When you specify the columns to insert, then you need to specify the columns in the VALUES part too:

```sql
INSERT INTO community_login_info (community_id,account_id,start_timestamp_login,eind_timestamp_login)
VALUES (t_communities_accounts(i_index).community_id,
        t_communities_accounts(i_index).account_id,
        t_communities_accounts(i_index).start_timestamp_login,
        t_communities_accounts(i_index).eind_timestamp_login);
```

If the table COMMUNITY_LOGIN_INFO doesn't have any more columns, you could use this syntax:

```sql
INSERT INTO community_login_info
VALUE (t_communities_accounts(i_index));
```

But I don't like performing inserts without specifying the columns because I could end up inserting the start time into the end time and vice versa if I haven't defined the columns in exactly the same order as the table definition, and if the definition of the table changes over time and new columns are added, you have to modify your procedure to add the new column even if the new column goes with a NULL value because you don't fill up that new column with this procedure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Oracle is known complaining that the types in the VALUE part aren't declared (PLS-00302, PLS-00382). I really don't understand why, I assume the collection knows these since I declared them as variables of the record variable I'm using to define the collection?

Comment: I changed the definition of the collection, instead of having a record variable where I refer to the different columns of the two tables involved, I simply referred to the target table instead (community_login_info%rowtype). Together with specifying the columns in the VALUES part like you indicated it now works! Code compiled and when running the procedure it generates random records as intended. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
PROCEDURE mass_add_rij_koppeling_community_login_info
IS
TYPE type_rec_communties_accounts IS RECORD
(type_community_id community.community_id%type,
type_account_id community_account.account_id%type,
type_start_timestamp_login community_account.start_timestamp_login%type,
type_eind_timestamp_login community_account.eind_timestamp_login%type);
TYPE type_tab_communities_accounts
IS TABLE of type_rec_communties_accounts
INDEX BY pls_integer;
t_communities_accounts type_tab_communities_accounts;
BEGIN
SELECT community_id,account_id,to_timestamp(start_datum_account) as start_timestamp_login, to_timestamp(eind_datum_account) as eind_timestamp_login 
BULK COLLECT INTO t_communities_accounts
FROM community
CROSS JOIN community_account
FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY;
FORALL i_index IN t_communities_accounts.first .. t_communities_accounts.last
SAVE EXCEPTIONS
INSERT INTO community_login_info (community_id,account_id,start_timestamp_login,eind_timestamp_login)
values (select community_id,account_id,start_timestamp_login,eind_timestamp_login
from table(cast(t_communities_accountsas type_tab_communities_accounts)) a);
END mass_add_rij_koppeling_community_login_info;
```

Comment: Tried this procedure but now I'm getting the error ORA-00936 'missing expression'. I thought maybe the select had to refer to the attributes of the record variable, but that didn't work either. I'm not familiar with the table() function though.

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct, although a bit convoluted. A bit more of information about why the OP is getting the error and what your solution fixes would be better.